# Sessionid not captured in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I was facing some issues while validating(co-relation?) of session ID .
[image]

While i have validated the token created before request the same xsid is not passing for next request.

Comment: Question is unclear: please include what/how do you expect xsid to be passed, and where that parameter (xsid) is supposed to be retrieved from.

Comment: Probably you add extra ' sign before session. What are you sending in sampler?